# Updating a Ionic framework project to the latest cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I recently ran the command:

```
cordova platform update iOS
```

Into my ionic framework projet, I got the result:

> iOS project is now at version 3.7.0

However the following command

```
cordova -v
```

gives me

> 4.2.0

Why is my project not updated to 4.2.0 ? Is there something preventing to upgrade from the 3.x to 4.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the cordova version is not the same as the platform one:

*For instance, the current 4.0.0 version will install iOS 3.6.3, android 3.6.4, browser 3.6.0, firefox os 3.6.3 etc*

[Here is a link](http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/) to read more about it

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked this?

http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#cordova-updates

Also, to update ionic itself, use `ionic` on your project directory. It will show when things are outdated. Update Ionic first, then cordova, then any other dependencies like platforms or ions.

Also be sure your node and npm are up to date.

UPDATE:

One more thing to keep in mind: be sure to install node, npm and ionic globally.